# Which checkbox in the CheckBoxList was just Checked (or Un-Checked)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this checkboxlist in the aspx file:

> ```
>         <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CBL_LOC" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
>             AutoPostBack="True" Font-Size="Small" Font-Names="Calibri">
>         </asp:CheckBoxList>
> ```

Items are added in the codebehind, based on user's previous input, like this:

```
    L = New ListItem
    L.Text = "ALL"
    L.Value = "ALL"
    L.Selected = True
    CBL_LOC.Items.Add(L)

    conn.ConnectionString = strConnString
    conn.Open()
    cmd = New SqlCommand(Sql, conn)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        L = New ListItem
        L.Text = dr(0)
        L.Value = dr(0)
        CBL_LOC.Items.Add(L)
        L.Selected = True
    End While
    dr.Close()
    cmd.Dispose()
    conn.Close()
```

Now, when the user checks (or unchecks) the "ALL" checkbox, I'm trying to check/uncheck all the items, using this code:

```
    Dim CBL As CheckBoxList = sender

    If (CBL.SelectedValue = "ALL") Then
        For Each I As ListItem In CBL_LOC.Items
            I.Selected = CBL.Items(0).Selected
        Next
    End If
```

This works fine when the ALL checkbox goes from unchecked to checked, the SelectedValue is "ALL".  But when "ALL" is unchecked, and user checks "ALL", the SelectedValue shows as the value of the first "checked" checkbox, not the "ALL" box.

Am I missing something here?  Is there a different/better way to determine which checkbox in the checkboxlist was just checked or unchecked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend making the select all and select none functionality be managed by controls outside of the check box list itself by creating two link buttons, because that will remove the `SelectedValue` checking logic; like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonAll" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButtonAll_Click">
    Select All
</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonNone" runat="server" 
                OnClick="LinkButtonNone_Click">
    Select None
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Now in the code-behind, have the two link buttons do their logic, like this:

```
' Check all item
Protected Sub LinkButtonAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each item As ListItem In CBL_LOC.Items
        item.Selected = True
    Next
End Sub

' Uncheck all items
Protected Sub LinkButtonNone_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each item As ListItem In CBL_LOC.Items
        item.Selected = False
    Next
End Sub
```

---

> Note: If you do not have `AutoEventWireup="true"` in your page, then you will need to append the `Handles` syntax to the end of the two sub-procedures.

Comment: You could (if you were so inclined) just set item.Selected to the opposite of what it's set to in one method, which would let you check/uncheck all with one button (which users are more used to seeing).

Comment: @Tim - fair enough, just wanted to present an alternative to the OP.

Comment: @Tim -- yeah -- but, I was also trying to allow user to select individual items when "ALL" is not checked, but unable to un-check any item if "ALL" is checked.  I may just put the 'controlling' ALL outside the checkboxlist. Good idea Karl, thanks